# write output while loop of console to a text file in java

Tags: java, io, console

I am new to Java and I am stuck at this part :

I am trying to output the console output into a text file using JAVA .
But the problem is I have a **While loop** running and my code writes the output to the file but deletes the previous one .
I want to append the while loop output to file .

Any help is appreciated . Thanks In advance :)

> PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
>
> System.setOut(out);

Comment: Just open the file once instead of every time through the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform the redirection *once*, and before you do anything else. i.e. before you enter your loop.

Note (also) that your shell can redirect to a file, and that might be preferable to changing the destination of `System.out`. That's feasible but perhaps unexpected for someone who's going to debug your code in the future and wonder where their output is going...

Or perhaps consider a [logging framework](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to `append` the new data to the previous data in the file, try this...

```
try{
    File f = new File("d:\\t.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f,true);    // true is for append
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    bw.append(Your_data);
  }catch(Exception ex){

       ex.printStackTrace();

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
  FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("output.txt",true);
  while(condition)
   {
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));

       System.setOut(out);

   }
```

where second argument to FileOutputStream will open it in appendable mode.